# Mamba installer complains about version which are already installed

Tags: conda, mamba

I'm trying to install pytorch into Anaconda with Mamba as given on their site.

```
mamba install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

But mamba complains

```
Encountered problems while solving:
  - package mamba-0.15.3-py39h951de11_0 requires libarchive >=3.5.1,<3.6.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package python-3.9.5-h12debd9_4 requires openssl >=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a, but none of the providers can be installed
```

However, when I list my already installed packages, the required version seem to be installed:

```
62:openssl                   1.1.1l               h7f8727e_0
44:libarchive                3.5.2                hccf745f_0    conda-forge
```

I only just installed mamba into a new Miniconda (with nomkl). conda runs for a very long time and also stops with some conflict information.

What can I do to install pytorch with the above command?

Comment: What platform are you on? Whose site are these instructions from?

Comment: Similar problem, on Linux Debian. Instructions are as per [installing pytorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/).  After a `conda create -n $myenv python=3.9 mamba -c conda-forge` then  `mamba install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia` quickly fails as reported above. Using conda instead spins wheels until it reports package conflict.

Comment: I’ve seen this happen when `channel_priority: strict` is used. Perhaps try switching to `flexible`, at least temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create the environment with pytorch as below, rather than first creating a skeleton environment using e.g. conda-forge, then installing pytorch from within the new environment with its `mamba` or `conda`. No idea why, but this seems to have done the trick for me. May be worth entering an issue on github.

```sh
# after activating the base conda environment
# update conda/mamba just in case, perhaps using conda-forge
conda update conda -c conda-forge
# `conda --version`: conda 4.10.3
conda update mamba -c conda-forge

myenv="fai_pt"
mamba create -n $myenv pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```